# How to be meditative and involved at work?

Tags: meditation, meditation-practicalities, meditation-effects, daily-life, meditation-hindrances

At work, I try to be mindful, deliberate, and calm. I found with the help of meditation and being mindful makes me less distracted and less stressed at my work or whatever I do. But I also feel being mindful, deliberate and calm makes me slow, feels less involved at my work(though I feel focused) and less energetic. I used to be very active and fast at certain stuffs I do but now I dont feel like that if try to be mindful.

How to overcome this? I want to be mindful and calm but I also want to be fast and involved at my work(or in other words highly active)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why the book *Flow* needs to be burned.

I'm going to let you in on a little secret - those periods where you are mindful and engaged?  You are actually moving faster than you think.  Possibly faster than you are when you feel that you are moving at a quicker clip.  When the mind moves slowly, it begins to see additional details.  Instead of your consciousness being smeared across a series of moments in an intoxicating blur of dopamine, now you are in particle after particle attention.  Persist long enough and you will even begin to see space between these very particles.  This can be very boring at first.  It's also uncomfortable.  But it is a gateway into your bigger mind.

There is a koan that asks why do you put on your seven piece robe at the sound of the bell?  I'm more inclined to ask you what is it like to put on that robe?  Where, then, is your mind as you carefully pull on your rakusu?

But there's a danger here.  The Zen patriarchs warn us to "live neither in the entanglement of outer things nor in inner feelings of emptiness".  While there is a danger of moving too fast and being dashed on the outer world, there is an equal danger of moving into pure quietism.  Those inner feelings of calm and collectedness are important, but they are not the whole story.  Speed and slowness are really no different.  When the barriers between subject and object begin to dissolve, you will arrive at a place that knows neither fast nor slow.

But for now, take it one moment at a time.

Comment: I want to know if I can balance that ? or am I missing something? In philosophical context what you say makes sense to me, but in reality i feel it is counterproductive